# Clojure - test for equality of function expression?

Tags: function, clojure, expression, equality

Suppose I have the following clojure functions:

```
(defn a [x] (* x x))

(def b (fn [x] (* x x)))

(def c (eval (read-string "(defn d [x] (* x x))")))
```

Is there a way to test for the equality of the function expression - some equivalent of

```
(eqls a b)
```

returns true?

Comment: Impossible -- equivalence of functions is undecidable.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the bounty comment format--didn't realize the formatting would not work the same way.

Comment: Hi Omri. If you see my answer below, you'll see that I talk about two functions which have the same JVM bytecode as their body. That is effectively intensional equality. I also make the point that intensional equality implies extensional equality (but that the reverse is not true). If the bytecode ends up being different (as it might for some of the examples that you give), then we're back to trying to achieve extensional equality - which as we know is undecideable. Hope that makes things a bit clearer - intensional equality (plus some special cases) is probably the best we can hope for.

Comment: @kittylyst Thanks for the response, and I find your answer thoughtful. I'm becoming convinced that the number of special cases (as you put it) is actually quite large, to the point where we could meaningfully test for function equivalence. For example, I think the case with `(* x x)` being equivalent to `(* x x 1)` could be solved by noting that the identity value of the `*` function is `1`. More generally, we could test for an identity value by getting the result of `(f)`. If the given `f` does have an identity value, we could ignore all such values in some `(f ...)` when equivalence testing.

Comment: @kittylyst Also: if you know a way to get the JVM bytecode of a function's body, I would love to learn how--that sounds pretty cool to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the above answers in regards to Clojure not having a built in ability to determine the equivalence of two functions and that it has been proven that you can not test programs functionally (also known as black box testing) to determine equality due to the halting problem (unless the input set is finite and defined).

I would like to point out that it is possible to algebraically determine the equivalence of two functions, even if they have different forms (different byte code).

The method for proving the equivalence algebraically was developed in the 1930's by Alonzo Church and is know as beta reduction in Lambda Calculus. This method is certainly applicable to the simple forms in your question (which would also yield the same byte code) and also for more complex forms that would yield different byte codes.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on precisely what you mean by "equality of the function expression".

These functions are going to end up as bytecode, so I could for example dump the bytecode corresponding to each function to a byte[] and then compare the two bytecode arrays.

However, there are many different ways of writing semantically equivalent methods, that wouldn't have the same representation in bytecode.

In general, it's impossible to tell what a piece of code does without running it. So it's impossible to tell whether two bits of code are equivalent without running both of them, on all possible inputs.

This is at least as bad, computationally speaking, as the halting problem, and possibly worse.

The halting problem is undecidable as it is, so the general-case answer here is definitely no (and not just for Clojure but for every programming language).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add to the excellent answers by others, but would like to offer another viewpoint that helped me. If you are e.g. testing that the correct function is returned from your own function, instead of comparing the function object you might get away with just returning the function as a `'symbol`.

I know this probably is not what the author asked for but for simple cases it might do.