# Testing function object (functor) equality, how is it evaluated? Do I use `is` or `==`?

Tags: python, function, equality, functor

Consider these functions:

```
def f():
    print("WTF?!")

def g():
    print("WTF?!")
```

They both do exactly the same thing, but a test of `f == g` still gives `False`. Do I assume from this that functor equality is evaluated by reference, and that there is no difference between `is` and `==`?

Whether or not that is the case, which one is better to use (even if only stylistically)?

By the way I'm primarily interested in Python 3 (Python 3.6).

**EDIT**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) is **not** a duplicate, I think. I understand the difference between reference equality and value equality, I just want to understand how `==` uses value equality (if at all) on functors.

Comment: This kind of comparison doesn't really make sense. Python is not a functional language in that way.

Comment: doing `print(f)` and `print(g)` will give you an idea was to why `f == g` returns `False`

Comment: @Chris_Rands thank you for pointing that out but I've read the main answer of that link (the rest TLDR so far) but that's not a duplicate. I understand the difference between reference equality and value equality, my question is about whether `==` uses value equality on functors and if so, how?

Comment: @Ray I removed my close vote, but what kind of comparison are you actually trying to do? What is your expected output for some examples?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, my understanding is that `print(f)` and `print(g)` explains why `f is g` returns `False`, not why `f == g` returns `False`.

Comment: @Ray I see your point. But there is no such thing as the value of a function if the function is **not called** (`f` vs `f()`). And that is why, to my understanding, `==` boils down to `is` as @MSeifert explains below.

Comment: @Chris_Rands my use case is that I have some script (main function) to run some numerical simulation and I want to easily substitute different subroutines (`f` and `g`) and I want to have the main function to test which subroutine (functor `f` or `g`) is passed and do different things accordingly.

Comment: You can't really determine if two nonpure functions are equal. With pure functions you can decide on a discrete domain `R` and then run a test like this: `for x in R: if f(x) != g(x): break # f!=g`

Comment: And you can probably use the `dis` module to make an equality operator that compares if the functions `f` and `g` *are written* in a similar way if that helps you at all

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059011/check-if-two-python-functions-are-equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function objects have no custom [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method (this method is called when comparing values with `==`) so they fall back to the superclasses `__eq__` method. In this case it's `object.__eq__` which, indeed, just compares if they are the [same object](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#is-not).

So:

```
>>> f == g
False
```

is identical (in this case) to:

```
>>> f is g
False
```

---

Just in case your interested how I know that functions have no custom `__eq__` method:

```
>>> type(f).__eq__ is object.__eq__
True
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I should have thought to test "type(f).__eq__ is object.__eq__" myself.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant , because of this :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem

Comment: Even though it's unlikely that the link goes stale it would be a better answer if you included the relevant portions in the answer itself.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that the above functions produce the same bytecode, and thus can be trivially compared using a sequence comparison.