# Compare 2 python codes automatically

Tags: python, diff

Okay, so I currently am working on a large python 2.7 codebase where my current task is as follows:

There are 2 modules say `A` and `B` which have a lot of similar code (I mean almost all methods are identical). My goal is to create a `Base` module to contain all the common code.

For this purpose I currently am manually reading and comparing functions (of the same name) between `A` and `B` to **see if they are same (or even almot same)or not**.

So is there a some way to automate this? Like a library like `diff` which is built to compare 2 python function codes to tell me if their content is same/almost same or not?

So for example currently I am working on 2 modules `ResourceStatusDB.py` and `ResourceStatusManagement.py`:

**ResourceStatusDB.py**

```
class ResourceManagementDB(BaseRSSDB):
.
.
.
def select(self, table, params):

    session = self.sessionMaker_o()
    XYZ()
    # finding the table
    found = False
    for ext in self.extensions:
      try:
        table_c = getattr(__import__(ext + __name__, globals(), locals(), [table]), table)
        found = True
        break
      except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        continue
    # If not found in extensions, import it from DIRAC base (this same module).
    if not found:
      table_c = getattr(__import__(__name__, globals(), locals(), [table]), table)
```

And **ResourceStatusManagement.py**
def select(self, table, params):

```
session = self.sessionMaker_o()
# finding the table
found = False
for ext in self.extensions:
  try:
    table_c = getattr(__import__(ext + __name__, globals(), locals(), [table]), table)
    found = True
    break
  except (ImportError, AttributeError):
    continue
# If not found in extensions, import it from DIRAC base (this same module).
if not found:
  table_c = getattr(__import__(__name__, globals(), locals(), [table]), table)
```

> Notice that the 2 functions are not exactly the same. (A difference of a few lines maybe possible). But still a majority of the logic is same at the function level. Any way to detect this?

Comment: If you're on *nix, you can use `diff`.

Comment: share at least some comparable fragments from 2 modules

Comment: most advanced text editors have a "compare" function, look at Notepad++ for instance

Comment: or load A into a git repo and then update it with B code and diff using git, etc. THere's many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059011/check-if-two-python-functions-are-equal

Comment: @ParthS007 its not a duplicate. I do not want to check if they are exactly equal or not.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have updated with an example

Comment: @heemayl I want to compare 2 functions and not the entire files. Also I know that I can do it with some programming + diff. I was just curious if there was some tool already available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is not python-related in my opinion ;P

Notepad++ has compare if u install addons
You can use winmerge, for file comparison

Total commander also in syncing folder has defualt tool to compare and modify.

Go with winmerge, best in my opinion.